# API timing out which uses DynamoDB scan(1000 records, 13.25mb size)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

we have an api in which it retrieve's 1000 records(13.25 MB) from DynamoDB table using scan operation. the lambda for that particular api is timing out after 30secs.

Is there a way to fetch all[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bGpc.png) the records at once.

Comment: you can increase the time out of lambda function, But why are you doing a scan on dyanmodb. **you must reconsider you design.**

Comment: even if I increase the time out of lambda function, but it still fails at API gateway, as you said either I should reconsider my design or should implement pagination feature without fetching all the records

But the problem with dynamodb is that the pagination can be achieved only through the lastevaluatedkey and no other option like retrieving the records say like from page 3 to page 4.

Comment: why do you need to go to page 3, why not just do a query?